# How to combine these two JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two JavaScript arrays below that both have the same number of entries, but that number can vary.

```
[{"branchids":"5006"},{"branchids":"5007"},{"branchids":"5009"}]      
[{"branchnames":"GrooveToyota"},{"branchnames":"GrooveSubaru"},{"branchnames":"GrooveFord"}]
```

I want to combine these two arrays so that I get

```
[{"5006":"GrooveToyota"},{"5007":"GrooveSubaru"},{"5008":"GrooveFord"}]
```

I'm not sure how to put it into words but hopefully someone understands. I would like to do this with two arrays of arbitrary length (both the same length though).

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: They guaranteed to be in the same order?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it just now that was a typo.

Comment: Uh, in your example they're all `5006`, which makes it even easier :(

Comment: Yes that was the typo I was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ids = [{"branchids":"5006"},{"branchids":"5007"},{"branchids":"5009"}];
var names = [{"branchnames":"GrooveToyota"},{"branchnames":"GrooveSubaru"},{"branchnames":"GrooveFord"}];
var combined = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var combinedObject = {};
    combinedObject[ids[i].branchids] = names[i].branchnames;
    combined.push(combinedObject);
}

combined; // [{"5006":"GrooveToyota"},{"5006":"GrooveSubaru"},{"5006":"GrooveFord"}]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's kind of a zip:

```
function zip(a, b) {
    var len = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        zipped = [],
        i, obj;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj= {};
        obj[a[i].branchids] = b[i].branchnames;
        zipped.push(obj);
    }
    return zipped;
}
```

[Example (uses console.log ie users)](http://jsfiddle.net/4VFQg/)

Comment: Do you mean 'i' instead of [0] in the fourth line from bottom?

Comment: Using [0] there won't work, as it will get GrooveToyota and 5006 each time. Also there is a syntax error. Here is a working version of your zip approach: http://jsfiddle.net/K5Mur/

Comment: @robert, you are correct sir. But it was a typo I've since fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do it IAbstractDownvoteFactor's way (+1), but for another option, I present the following for your coding pleasure:

```
var a = [{"branchids":"5006"},{"branchids":"5007"},{"branchids":"5009"}];
var b = [{"branchnames":"GrooveToyota"},{"branchnames":"GrooveSubaru"},{"branchnames":"GrooveFord"}];
var zipped = a.map(function(o,i){ var n={};n[o.branchids]=b[i].branchnames;return n;});
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to @robert solution but using Array.prototype.map

var ids = [{"branchids":"5006"},{"branchids":"5007"},{"branchids":"5009"}],
    names = [{"branchnames":"GrooveToyota"},{"branchnames":"GrooveSubaru"},{"branchnames":"GrooveFord"}],
    merged = ids.map(function (o, i) { var obj = {}; obj[o.branchids]=names[i].branchnames; return obj; });

merged; //[{5006: "GrooveToyota"}, {5006: "GrooveSubaru"}, {5006:"GrooveFord"}]

Cheers!